# How to show the exact line of code in Lumen where error occured?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have a syntax error in my test. For example:

```
  /** @test **/
public function show_should_return_a_valid_book()
{
    $this
        ->get('/books/1')
        ->seeStatusCode(200)
        ->seeJson([
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'War of the Worlds',
            'description' => 'A science fiction masterpiece about martians invading London',
            'author' => 'H. G. Wells'
        ]);
    $data = json_decode($this->response->getContent(), true);
    $this-> assertArrayHasKey('created_at'), $data);
    $this-> assertArrayHasKey('updated_at'), $data);
}
```

Here I've forgot to place left parentheses in last two lines.

If I do that in Laravel, I get the message:

> C:\phpcode\shopcart>phpunit
>   PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',' in      C:\phpcode\shopcart\tests\Test
>   Test.php on line 33
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\phpcode\shopcart\tests\TestTest.
>   php on line 33

which is pretty nice because I can see where exatly the error happened.

But when it comes to Lumen all I see is:

> C:\phpcode\lumenbook>phpunit
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

How could I get something more verbose in Lumen?

Comment: Did you try `phpunit -vvv` ?

Comment: Yes and to no avail. Reading phpunit documentation is the first thing I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited one line in

> %projname%\symphony\debug\Exception\FatalErrorException.php

```
// $message = 'Parse error: '.$e->getMessage();
```

became

```
$message = 'Parse error; ' .$e->getMessage() .' in file ' .$e->getFile() 
.'at line ' .$e->getLine();
```

Don't know whether it's elegant solution or not but it works for now.

Comment: Got it. The solution above can be helpful if I need to see the problem right in command line. The simplest way is just to look what exactly happened in storage\logs\lumen.log